# uniform convergence of $u_\varepsilon(x)=-\varepsilon\log\left(\frac{\cosh(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})}{\cosh(\frac{1}{\varepsilon})}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to prove that the sequence
$$u_\varepsilon(x)=-\varepsilon\log\left(\frac{\cosh(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})}{\cosh(\frac{1}{\varepsilon})}\right)$$ converges uniformly to $u(x)=1-|x|$ for $\varepsilon\to 0$ and $x\in [-1,1]$.

To simplify the notation I replace $\varepsilon$ with $\frac{1}{n}$ and consider the limit $n\to\infty$ instead of $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Now I have to show that $$\sup_{x\in [-1,1]} \left|u_\varepsilon(x)-u(x)\right|\to 0\ \mathrm{as}\ n\to\infty$$

Thus far my estimate looks like this (I'm leaving out the $\sup$ to shorten the notation):

\begin{align*}
& \left|-\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{e^{nx}+e^{-nx}}{e^{n}+e^{-n}}\right)-1+|x|\right| \\
 = & \left|-\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{e^{n(x-1)}+e^{-n(x+1)}}{1+e^{-2n}}\right)-1+|x|\right|
\end{align*}

Since $x\in [-1,1]$ we have $e^{-n(x+1)}\leq 1$ and $e^{-2n}\geq 0$. Hence

$$\leq\left|-\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{e^{n(x-1)}+1}{1}\right)-1+|x|\right|$$

Now I use the estimate $\log |x|\leq |x|$ for $|x|\leq 1$:

$$\leq\left|-\frac{1}{n}\left|e^{n(x-1)}+1\right|-1+|x|\right|$$

With the estimate $e^x\leq 2+x$ for $|x|\leq 1$ and the triangle inequality we have

\begin{align*}
\leq & \left|-\frac{1}{n}\left|nx-n+3\right|-1+|x|\right|\\
\leq & \left|-|x-1|-\frac{3}{n} - 1 + |x|\right|
\end{align*}

But I cannot show that this converges to $0$.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $u_\varepsilon$ is an even function, we can, to simplifiy nottaion, assume that $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$. To identify the behaviour, we write

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{n}\log \frac{e^{nx}+e^{-nx}}{e^n+e^{-n}} - 1 + x
&= -\frac{1}{n}\log \frac{e^{-n(1-x)} + e^{-n(x+1)}}{1+e^{-2n}} - 1 + x\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\log (1+e^{-2n}) - \frac{1}{n}\log (e^{-n(1-x)}+e^{-n(1+x)}) - 1 + x\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\log (1+e^{-2n}) - \frac{1}{n}\log (1+e^{-2nx}) + \frac{n(1-x)}{n}-1+x\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\log (1+e^{-2n}) - \frac{1}{n}\log (1+e^{-2nx})
\end{align}

and hence obtain

$$\left\lvert -\frac{1}{n}\log \frac{e^{nx}+e^{-nx}}{e^n+e^{-n}} - 1 + x\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{\log 2}{n},$$

since $1 \leqslant 1+e^{-2n} \leqslant 2$ and $1 \leqslant 1+e^{-2nx} \leqslant 2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I don't understand, though, is why this equality holds: $$\frac{1}{n}\log (1+e^{-2n}) - \frac{1}{n}\log (e^{-n(1-x)}+e^{-n(1+x)}) - 1 + x= \frac{1}{n}\log (1+e^{-2n}) - \frac{1}{n}\log (1+e^{-2nx}) + \frac{n(1-x)}{n}-1+x$$

Comment: Write $$e^{-n(1-x)} + e^{-n(1+x)} = e^{-n(1-x)}\left(1 + e^{n(1-x)}e^{-n(1+x)}\right),$$ use $\log (ab) = \log a + \log b$ for $a,b > 0$, and $e^{n(1-x)}e^{-n(1+x)} = e^{-2nx}$.

Comment: okay, thanks for elaborating!